# jsf ajax bootstrap dropdown render

Tags: ajax, jsf, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making form with dropdowns, where user have to make first choice, than using ajax next choices appear. It works just fine. But I wanted to add bootstrap formatting for dropodwns, so I installed bootstrap-select. It work also just fine, but when ajax event renders data for next  he renders it in a new dropdown, next to still empty bootstrap formated dropdown. Witch, how can you predict, isn't desired action. Here's code from jsf:

```
<h:selectOneMenu styleClass="bootstrap-select" id="marka" value="#{searchBean.markiID}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{searchBean.listaMarek}" var="c" itemLabel="#{c.marka}"
                               itemValue="#{c.markaID}"/>
                <f:ajax event="change" execute="marka" render="model"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>

            <h:outputText value="#{msg.carModel}"></h:outputText>
            <h:selectOneMenu styleClass="bootstrap-select" id="model" value="#{searchBean.modelID}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{searchBean.listaModeli}" var="p" itemLabel="#{p.model}"
                               itemValue="#{p.modelID}"/>
                <f:ajax event="change" execute="model" render="liczbaDrzwi"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
```

[image]

In backingbean, when user choose smthging from first dropdown, Is generated list of items for second dropdown, and so on. And this is the result of making choice:

[image]

As you can see, ajax makes totally new dropdown, instead of filling already existing.

Thanks for any ideas:)

Answer (score 0):

JSF Ajax works in this way... instead of filling the already existing dropdown... the jee server send a new HTML fragment to replace this dropdown code... 
Maybe you could read this link to understand JSF lifecycle...[jsf lifeclycle](http://balusc.blogspot.com.ar/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html)

Did you try using primefaces or richfaces instead of h:selectOneMenu component?

Here is a PrimeFaces example where you can see how to update one dropdown when you select a value on another dropdown... [pf example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprSelect.jsf)